# how to make program i made by java know certain file types?

Tags: java, swing

How to make program i made by java know certain file types and make windows open that certain extension by it ?

How i can put a picture to put it for that extension when it's the default program ?

As example when i setup a FOX-IT reader it terns all PDFs files into FOX-IT reader & the FOX-IT picture putted on the PDFs files also ?

if there is a class that access a certain file in windows ?

Comment: that's not google... You have to explain clearly what you want to do and what you tried. What are those `Blockquote`?

Comment: You might wanna read on [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)... or I think you are looking to make your application the default [application to open a file of a certain extension.](http://superuser.com/questions/144573/set-default-file-opening-programs)

Comment: Thanks for replying , what i want to do is to make my program make the WINDOS to open all files that .jpeg with my program automatically

Comment: If you want to register your program as the program responsible for certain file types, you need to edit the registry. I'm not 100% sure if this question belongs here or should be moved to http://superuser.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about changing Windows settings, rather than anything to do with your program itself.
This is a question about Windows, not about Java.

Normally, you would hold shift while right-clicking on the file, select "Open With" and then pick the program that you want to use to open the file type.

However, since you are talking about a Java program, you probably don't have an executable to run.

In this case, you will need to create the association in the registry yourself.

**As always when dealing with the registry, don't change things there unless you know what you are doing, as you can break your system.**

Under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, create a new key for your file type.  I'll use the ".abc" extension for this example, so first create a new key with the name ".abc".
Set the (Default) value of your key to "abcfile"
Now, create another key (again under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) named "abcfile".  The (Default) value here is the name you will see in the Type column.
Add the following tree of keys underneath abcfile:
abcfile

| shell

+-| open

--+--| command

In the (Default) value of "command", put in the command that you wish to run when opening the file.  Use quotes for paths with spaces, and "%1" in place of the filename.

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\path\to\jar\MyJar.jar" "%1"
```

To change the icon, you will need to make another key under "abcfile" named "DefaultIcon".

Set the (Default) value of this key to the path to your icon file.

Comment: No i want to put a code in my program to make windos put the picture on jpeg files and open them automatically when i install the progrm without making it my self from open with

Comment: Then you need your installer to make changes such as the above to the registry, based on the path where Java is installed (you may need to find this in your installer program) and the path where you installed your application to.

The registry controls file associations, if you want to change them, then you'll need to make changes there somehow.

I edited the above post to include mention of how to set an icon.

Answer (score 0):

To open an application associated with the file extension you'll need to use the `java.awt.Desktop` class.  Oracle has [a tutorial with sample code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).

Getting the icon for an application is more difficult.  Your best course of action is to include standard icons as resources in your application; that should cover most scenarios.